# Codacy API: Send API Code for Analyzation

Tags: codacy

Is it possible to use the Codacy API to analyze a snippet of code? We would like to analyze code without creating a GitHub repo for the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, codacy only integrates with git repositories at this moment

Answer (score 3):

You can try to analyse your project/snippet of code locally, using [codacy-analysis-cli that is available on github](https://github.com/codacy/codacy-analysis-cli) and is still under development.